# Error to run Docker for AWS SAM - Lambda Debug in VScode

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, visual-studio-code, aws-sam

I want to debug locally my Lambda, and after config `AWS SAM and AWS Toolkit`, I'm able to run `sam build` but when I try to invoke the function or, most important, run in vscode debug mode, I get this error for (i think) docker:

```
2022-06-06 16:51:08 [INFO]: Preparing to debug locally: Lambda "lambda_function.lambda_handler"
2022-06-06 16:51:08 [INFO]: Building SAM application...
2022-06-06 16:51:10 [INFO]: Command: (not started) [C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\bin\sam.cmd build --build-dir C:\Users\poliian\AppData\Local\Temp\aws-toolkit-vscode\vsctkUxOcxJ\output --template C:/Users/poliian/AppData/Local/Temp/aws-toolkit-vscode/vsctkUxOcxJ/app___vsctk___template.yaml --base-dir C:/Users/poliian/git/EU8/informacoesfiscaislegais-automacaooslambdaespec --manifest C:\Users\poliian\AppData\Local\Temp\aws-toolkit-vscode\vsctkUxOcxJ\debug-requirements.txt]
2022-06-06 16:51:13 [INFO]: Building codeuri: C:/Users/poliian/git/EU8/informacoesfiscaislegais-automacaooslambdaespec runtime: python3.9 metadata: {} architecture: x86_64 functions: ['informacoesfiscaislegaisautomacaooslambdaespec']

2022-06-06 16:51:14 [INFO]: Running PythonPipBuilder:ResolveDependencies

2022-06-06 16:51:19 [INFO]: Running PythonPipBuilder:CopySource

2022-06-06 16:51:19 [INFO]: 
Build Succeeded

2022-06-06 16:51:19 [INFO]: 
Built Artifacts  : ..\..\Users\poliian\AppData\Local\Temp\aws-toolkit-vscode\vsctkUxOcxJ\output
Built Template   : ..\..\Users\poliian\AppData\Local\Temp\aws-toolkit-vscode\vsctkUxOcxJ\output\template.yaml

Commands you can use next
=========================
[*] Validate SAM template: sam validate
[*] Invoke Function: sam local invoke -t ..\..\Users\poliian\AppData\Local\Temp\aws-toolkit-vscode\vsctkUxOcxJ\output\template.yaml
[*] Test Function in the Cloud: sam sync --stack-name {stack-name} --watch
[*] Deploy: sam deploy --guided --template-file ..\..\Users\poliian\AppData\Local\Temp\aws-toolkit-vscode\vsctkUxOcxJ\output\template.yaml
        

2022-06-06 16:51:20 [INFO]: Build complete.
2022-06-06 16:51:20 [INFO]: Starting SAM application locally
2022-06-06 16:51:25 [INFO]: AWS.running.command
Invoking lambda_function.lambda_handler (python3.9)
Skip pulling image and use local one: public.ecr.aws/sam/emulation-python3.9:rapid-1.51.0-x86_64.

Mounting C:\Users\poliian\AppData\Local\Temp\aws-toolkit-vscode\vsctkUxOcxJ\output\informacoesfiscaislegaisautomacaooslambdaespec as /var/task:ro,delegated inside runtime container
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\docker\api\client.py", line 261, in _raise_for_status
    response.raise_for_status()
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 943, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error for url: http+docker://localnpipe/v1.35/containers/create

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

docker.errors.APIError: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error ("b'status code not OK but 500: \x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0c\x02\x00\x00\x00BDocker.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null\x05\x01\x00\x00\x00\x1bDocker.Core.DockerException\x0c\x00\x00\x00\tClassName\x07Message\x04Data\x0eInnerException\x07HelpURL\x10StackTraceString\x16RemoteStackTraceString\x10RemoteStackIndex\x0fExceptionMethod\x07HResult\x06Source\rWatsonBuckets\x01\x01\x03\x03\x01\x01\x01\x00\x01\x00\x01\x07\x1eSystem.Collections.IDictionary\x10System.Exception\x08\x08\x02\x02\x00\x00\x00\x06\x03\x00\x00\x00\x1bDocker.Core.DockerException\x06\x04\x00\x00\x00\x1eFilesharing has been cancelled\n\n\n\x06\x05\x00\x00\x00\x8c\x13   at Docker.ApiServices.Mounting.FileSharing.<DoShareAsync>d__7.MoveNext() in C:\\workspaces\\PR-16070\\src\\github.com\\docker\\pinata\\win\\src\\Docker.ApiServices\\Mounting\\FileSharing.cs:line 0\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Docker.ApiServices.Mounting.FileSharing.<ShareAsync>d__5.MoveNext() in C:\\workspaces\\PR-16070\\src\\github.com\\docker\\pinata\\win\\src\\Docker.ApiServices\\Mounting\\FileSharing.cs:line 53\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Docker.HttpApi.Controllers.FilesharingController.<ShareDirectory>d__2.MoveNext() in C:\\workspaces\\PR-16070\\src\\github.com\\docker\\pinata\\win\\src\\Docker.HttpApi\\Controllers\\FilesharingController.cs:line 21\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.<CastToObject>d__1`1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__15.MoveNext()\n\x00\x00\x00\x00\x06\x06\x00\x00\x00\x9f\x018\nMoveNext\nDocker.ApiServices, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null\nDocker.ApiServices.Mounting.FileSharing+<DoShareAsync>d__7\nVoid MoveNext()\x00\x15\x13\x80\x06\x07\x00\x00\x00\x12Docker.ApiServices'")

Command stopped: "sam local invoke"
2022-06-06 16:51:28 [ERROR]: Failed to run SAM application locally: "sam local invoke" command stopped (error code: 1)
```

I tried to configure docker File Sharing to `AppData\Local\Temp\aws-toolkit-vscode` path.
One important thing is that I'm on my business env so I don't know if this is an access problem or docker config problem, because when I try to run on my personal notebook run normally.

My launch.json as well:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "aws-sam",
            "request": "direct-invoke",
            "name": "informacoesfiscaislegais-automacaooslambdaespec:DevHello",
            "invokeTarget": {
                "target": "template",
                "templatePath": "${workspaceFolder}/app/template.yaml",
                "logicalId": "DevHello"
            },
            "lambda": {
                "payload": {},
                "environmentVariables": {}
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "aws-sam",
            "request": "direct-invoke",
            "name": "informacoesfiscaislegais-automacaooslambdaespec:DevHello",
            "invokeTarget": {
                "target": "template",
                "templatePath": "${workspaceFolder}/app/template.yaml",
                "logicalId": "DevHello"
            },
            "lambda": {
                "runtime": "python3.9",
                "payload": {},
                "environmentVariables": {}
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Edit 1:

When I Use the WSL 2 based engine I get a new error (and the previously error happening when I turn it of):

[image]

I don't know what can be this. I already searched on google, stack, github, aws pages and I can find any solution for this.